# How to put haproxy in front of socket.io with SSL? Getting Mixed content warning

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, ssl, haproxy

I have been using this [setting](https://gist.github.com/christiannelson/3900758) to put haproxy in front of node.js and socket.io.

Some of the code in haproxy setting:

```
frontend wwws
    bind 0.0.0.0:443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/ovee.pem
    timeout client 1h
    default_backend www_backend

    acl is_websocket hdr(Upgrade) -i WebSocket
    use_backend websocket_backend if is_websocket

    tcp-request inspect-delay 500ms
    tcp-request content accept if HTTP
    use_backend flashsocket_backend if !HTTP

frontend flash_policy
    bind 0.0.0.0:843
    timeout client 5s
    default_backend nodejs_flashpolicy

backend www_backend
    balance roundrobin
    option forwardfor
    server apache2 apache-backend:3001 weight 1 maxconn 1024 check  
    timeout connect 5s
    timeout http-request 3s
    timeout server 25s

backend websocket_backend
    mode http
    option forwardfor
    option http-server-close
    option forceclose
    no option httpclose
    server server1 socket-backend:3000 weight 1 maxconn 16384 check
```

nodeServer.js

```
var fs =    require('fs');
var express = require('express'), 
app = express(), 
http = require('http').createServer(app), 
io = require("socket.io").listen(http),
```

It seems to work well on first connection, but then the browser are blocking all the socket connection attempts for `Mixed Content`.

```
The page at 'https://domain.com/391' was loaded over HTTPS, 
 but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 
'http://domain.com:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1456666556035-0'. 
 This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

I know it's due to my connection to socket.io is via `Http` instead of `Https`

client.js

```
socket = io.connect('http://domain.com:3000', {
  'force new connection': false,
  'reconnection delay': 500,
  'max reconnection attempts': 10
}),
```

I have tried using SSL for nodeServer.js, but that doesn't connect to the socket, and I don't think it is necessary since I'm using haproxy to do all the forwarding:

In nodeServer.js, I have changed to:

```
var fs =    require('fs'),
sslOption = {
    key:    fs.readFileSync('/ssl/crt/zz.key'),
    cert:   fs.readFileSync('/ssl/crt/zz.crt'),
    ca:     fs.readFileSync('/ssl/crt/zz-ca.crt'),
    requestCert: true
},
express = require('express'), 
app = express(), 
https = require('https').createServer(app), 
io = require("socket.io").listen(https),
```

client.js

```
socket = io.connect('https://domain.com:3000', {
  'force new connection': false,
  'reconnection delay': 500,
  'max reconnection attempts': 10
}),
```

Has anyone put haproxy in front of node.js and socket.io? What should I use to connect to socket.io from the client.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have somehow solved the problem. I shouldn't have use `https:domain.com:3000` in `client.js`. I should let the haproxy do the SSL forwarding. Here's my settings to make SSL work with socket.io. I hope someone who may stumble upon it would correct anything that is outdated or wrong:

```
frontend www

    bind 0.0.0.0:80

    mode http

    timeout client 5s

    redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }

    acl is_socket hdr(Upgrade) -i WebSocket

    acl is_socket hdr_beg(Host) -i wss

    use_backend socket if is_socket

frontend www-https

   bind 0.0.0.0:443 ssl crt /ssl/domain.pem

   timeout client  1h


   ### Set up a check to identify the connection url initated by socket.io https://domain.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1441877956651, if matched, forward to node backend

   acl is_node path_beg /socket.io/ 

   use_backend node if is_websocket


   ### I'm not sure if this one is necessary for wss://domain.com

   acl is_websocket2 hdr(Upgrade) -i WebSocket

   acl is_websocket2 hdr_beg(Host) -i ws

   use_backend socket if is_websocket2

   default_backend apache2

   tcp-request inspect-delay 500ms

   tcp-request content accept if HTTP

   use_backend flashsocket_backend if !HTTP


frontend flash_policy

    bind 0.0.0.0:843

    timeout client 5s

    default_backend nodejs_flashpolicy

###  setting for apache, skipped because it's not the focus of the question 

backend apache

### 

backend flashsocket_backend
    server server1 ipaddress:3000 weight 1 maxconn 16384 check

backend nodejs_flashpolicy
    server server1 ipaddress:10843 maxconn 16384 check


backend node

    mode http 

    timeout server 1h

    timeout connect 1s  

    option httpclose

    option forwardfor

    server server1 ipaddress:3000 weight 1 maxconn 1024 check


backend socket

    balance roundrobin

    option forwardfor

    option httpclose

    timeout queue 5000

    timeout server 86400000

    timeout connect 86400000

    server server1 127.0.0.1:9000 weight 1 maxconn 1024 check
```

Then in client.js, I have changed the connection address to:

```
socket = io.connect('https://domain.com', {
  'force new connection': false,
  'reconnection delay': 500,
  'max reconnection attempts': 10,
})
```

Use 'https://domain.com' instead of 'http://domain.com:3000' so that the connection will first pass to ha-proxy.

There is nothing required to be changed in `nodeServer.js`. Keep using `http` and Haproxy will do all the SSL forwarding for you.

```
var fs =    require('fs'),
express = require('express'), 
app = express(), 
http = require('http').createServer(app), 
io = require("socket.io").listen(http),
```